# Logitech Options for Ubuntu

Tags: 19.04, logitech

i recently bought a Logitech MX Ergo Trackball and wanted to use the feature which allows you by pressing a button to switch between Computers. For that to work *Logitech Options* needs to be installed on both Computers. Unfortunately Logitech does not provide this software for Linux/Ubuntu.

Is there a way to get the software running on my Ubuntu system?

Any information or advice is appreciated.

Comment: I have no idea how it connects (wifi? usb?) but you could always *sniff* the traffic, re-play what you heard and write a script that transmits that traffic to the device  - but this is guess as I don't know the device you mention, and this would require some scripting skill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually need Logitech Options installed on your linux machine.  Just pair your device using the USB dongle or bluetooth (may need a bluetooth dongle if your box doesn't have bluetooth already).  I switch my Logitech mouse and keyboard between my Ubuntu box, Windows box, and Macbook Pro using the buttons on the Logitech devices without any problems.

Comment: The problem is, that if I pair the device with 2 dongles only one works at a time (the last i paired it with). So even if i connect one dongle to my notebook and one to my PC only one works.

Comment: The logitech devices can only be paired to a single usb.  To use between multiple machines, the other machines need to be paired using bluetooth.  For example, you can have 1 usb + 2 bluetooth, or 3 bluetooth.  Even with Logitech Options installed, this still holds true.

Comment: Oh wow i completly forgot about the bluetooth option WITHOUT the usb-device. This clearly solved it. Thank you.

Comment: So it's a bit roundabout but I just had to deal with this problem and I worked out a way to accomplish this with two Logi receivers rather than having to resort to bluetooth.

The tricky part is that if you plug both receivers in to one computer, you can only pair a given device to one receiver. So, split them. Mouse on one, keyboard on the other. Unplug one receiver, then use the other to pair. That will work since they aren't both plugged in at the same time. Then unplug the first receiver, plug in the second, and pair the other. You can then transfer either receiver to Ubuntu.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, it's an advertisement. There are all kinds of configurable options on logitech devices that you cannot adjust via the Ubuntu interface (or doing so would be too time-consuming to imagine). As much of Logitech has switched to Bluetooth, there's no way to edit many things via Solaar. (Yes I realize this is a year old, hence the comment.)

Comment: You can pair easily enough with either Bluetooth or the USB dongle, but you will need the Logitech software installed to copy/paste between computers, and Logi only make this available for Windows and Mac. There is no *Logitech Flow* available for Linux.

Answer (score 4):

You don't actually need Windows to pair the trackball, [ltunify](https://github.com/Lekensteyn/ltunify) will let you do this on Linux. Just follow the guide on the page (ie. turn off your MX Ergo, run ltunify, turn on the MX Ergo again, done). If you don't want to mess with the user permissions, you can just run ltunify with sudo.

Once you're paired, you can change the settings (HID++ Scrolling and pointer sensitivity) using [Solaar](https://pwr-solaar.github.io/Solaar/).

I just got my MX Ergo in the mail, so can confirm that this process works per the current date :)

Comment: `Solaar` was the name I was looking for; it's been awhile.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the reputation to make comments therefore this "answer" is an answer to @guiverc. I'm not totally sure on how the ergo is working but I have the MX key and MX master 3 and they both have a USB receiver and can also be used with Bluetooth. Logitech states on their danish site that the MX key should have the opportunity to switch among computers:

> you just need the Logitech-flow and logitech-options which can be
>   downloaded here: https://www.logitech.com/da-dk/product/options

Comment: It only supports Windows and MacOS